Tailwind style element based on child attributes
I am having a difficult time trying to style a td element  which has a div that has a class called 'check' as its child element. I am trying to style it from div element which is the parent of  the table.
This is my selector in the below example:
<div class="[&>table>tbody>tr>td:has-[ .check]]:bg-gray-100">
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="check">...</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

I am not that fluent with tailwind. What is it that I am doing wrong and how can I fix it
I've tried achieving this using the has- modifier
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-descendants

Updated Answer
While you cannot style a parent depending on the children by :has-[.CLASS], you can do so by javascript.


document.querySelectorAll('.table-container td').forEach(td => {
  td.querySelector('.check') && td.classList.add('bg-gray-100');
});
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="check">This one will be highlighted</div></td>
        <td><div>This one NOT!</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



Orginal Answer
You cannot select a class with the has-{modifier}, you can only select an element by either a pseudo-class or by the tag name.
As per TailwindCSS

You can use has-* with a pseudo-class, like has-[:focus], to style an element based on the state of its descendants. You can also use element selectors, like has-[img] or has-[a], to style an element based on the content of its descendants.

However, you can achive that without has-* simply by selecting the element with .check class like the following:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="[&>table>tbody>tr>td>.check]:bg-gray-100">
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="check">...</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




Thanks for the clarity. But this targets the div element. I want to target the parent (td) element of the div element that has 'check' as a class name.

@mogale Sorry for the confusion. is it okay for you to use javascript? it requires two lines of code.

I think has-[>table>tbody>tr>td>.check]:bg-gray-100 is what you need.
Tailwind Playground
Update
To target the td parent of .check.
<td class="has-[>.check]:bg-gray-100"><div class="check">...</div></td>
Tailwind Playground
Update2

target td not .check
Write class on the div

<div class="[&>table>tbody>tr>td:has(.check)]:bg-gray-500">
Tailwind Playground

I think that affects the entire table rather that the table cell

How about move the class to the td, <td class="has-[>.check]:bg-gray-100"><div class="check">...</div></td> https://play.tailwindcss.com/KcV9LUQvls

The <td> element has been abstract away in our codebase, so I can't style it directly. Hence, if you look at my code, I am targeting the <td> component from an upper <div> component.

[&>table>tbody>tr>td:has(.check)]:bg-gray-500 on div should fit your need, check this.
